# Boot to Kiosk Mode with Python Script

Tags: python, boot, kiosk

I am trying to get a python script with tkinter GUI to run in kiosk mode on startup without loading the entire X environments desktop and everything else.

I have the following script in ~/.xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /home/pi/test.py --kiosk
```

Using Rasps-Config, if I boot to the console with auto login and type startx, then it works perfectly.  However, if I boot to the desktop environment it loads the complete desktop and my script never runs.  If I boot to the console and place a script in rc.local that runs startx, it still goes to the complete environment without running my script.  However, I do get an error saying "no session for pid 786".

In this usage case, I do not have access to a keyboard so I am unable to type startx from the console to make it boot correctly.

Anyway have and ideas or solutions?

By the way, I'm running a Pi 3 with the latest image of stretch.  It's a clean install except for the software to run Adafruit's 2.4" PiTFT screen.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have answered my own question.  When booting to desktop with auto login, the ~/.xinitrc file was not being read.  I moved the same script to ~/.xsession and it seems to be working correctly now.